# How to have a mongoose database model that references to another variable model?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have Database of a website where I store all the content in an array (This content is editable for privileged users) Array has a one field called type which is the type of Component and and it also has an array which contains all extra information.

This is the Data.json:

```
[
    {
    "type" :"Navbar", 
    "extra":[]
    },
    {
    "type" :"Header",
    "extra":[ 
                "Welcome To Our Studio!",
                "IT'S NICE TO MEET YOU"
            ]
    },
    { 
    "type" :"Services",
    "extra":[
            "SERVICES",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.",
            "E-Commerce",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.",
            "Responsive Design",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.",
            "Web Security",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit."
            ]
    },
    {
    "type" :"About",
    "extra":
        [
            "About",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi velit modi magnam atque iste delectus assumenda inventore nam iusto quo. Facilis, expedita laudantium at itaque soluta aliquid hic obcaecati reprehenderit."
        ]
    },
    {
    "type" :"Team",
    "extra":[
            "Our Amazing Team",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.",
            "Kay Garland",
            "Lead Designer",
            "Larry Parker",
            "Lead Marketer",
            "Diana Pertersen",
            "Lead Developer",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eaque, laboriosam veritatis, quos non quis ad perspiciatis, totam corporis ea, alias ut unde."
        ]
    },
    {
    "type": "Contact",
    "extra":[
            "Contact Us",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want to have this extra details as a object. (So that when user edit this info I don't have to change whole document)

like for header I want model of extra to be :

```
extra: {
  header : {type : String},
  Subheader : {type : String}
}
```

and for Services I want that model to be :

```
extra: {
  header : {type : String },
  Subheader : {type :  String},
  servicesName1:{type :  String},
  serviceDetails1:{type :  String},
  servicesName2: {type :  String},
  serviceDetails2:{type :  String},
  servicesName3: {type : String},
  serviceDetails3:{type :  String}
}
```

I am confused that How I can refrence this variable models in my code. Or if there is any other option that any one can think of.

This is the schema that I have used how would I change this so that it can solve this issue?

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    data: [{
    type : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    extra : [{
      type: String,
    }]
  }],
});
```

Comment: [Discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html). Note, removed all the other tags on your question since basically "MongoDB itself" is *schemaless*. Mongoose is the only thing enforcing a certain structure on your documents, so that is the only thing really valid to the question. But you really need to read the referenced manual page and understand that.

Comment: @kaushik please add your actual mongoose schemas to the question: you've tagged `mongoose` your question but I can't see any mongoose code here...

Comment: @lifeisfoo hi thanks for the reply. I have added my existing schema in the question.